# KQL: How to create new fields of keys and values from a field with JSON object?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have a field in Azure monitor log which is in JSON format, and here is an example:

```
{
  "industry": ["Health"],
  "autoAbstractRegions": ["United States"],["Canada"] 
}
```

Can someone teach me how to create two new fields of keys and values from this? I also need to use mv-expand to expands the original rows into separate rows for each value.

I managed to create a new field of keys by using:

```
| extend keys = bag_keys(Filters)

| mv-expand keys
```

However, I have no clue how create the field of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create key and values field from the JSON field, you can use mv-apply operator. Below is the example to do this.

```
let MyTable = datatable(MyJson:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({
        "industry": ["Health"],
        "autoAbstractRegions": ["United States", "Canada"]
    })
];
MyTable
| mv-apply MyJson on(
extend key = tostring(bag_keys(MyJson)[0])
 | project key, value = MyJson[key]
 )
 | mv-expand value
```

In this query, the  `mv-apply`  operator is used to apply a subquery to each row of the  `MyJson`  column. The subquery uses the  `extend`  operator to create a new field of keys, and the  `project`  operator to project the keys and values into separate columns. The  `mv-expand`  operator is then used to expand the values into separate rows.

**Output:**

| **key** | **value** |
| --- | --- |
| industry | Health |
| autoAbstractRegions | United States |
| autoAbstractRegions | Canada |